# pull the table mapping in a GoldenGate replicat program

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following requirement. I need to list down all the tables from Golden Gate prm files. I want to use regex to pull the list from the chunk of string. The format of data looks like this:

```
MAP  AFF_INTEGRATION.SFDC_ACCOUNT , Target dbo.AFF_INTEGRATION_SFDC_ACCOUNT_EXCEPTION ,

--MAP AFF_INTEGRATION.SFDC_USER , Target er_service.dbo.AFF_INTEGRATION_SFDC_USER ,
```

I want the data in a tabulated format:

```
AFF_INTEGRATION.SFDC_ACCOUNT        dbo.AFF_INTEGRATION_SFDC_ACCOUNT_EXCEPTION
```

Note: The lines that contains `--` should be ignored.

**Edit:** Updated the text input text in the question. So basically I have to split the contents after `MAP` and ending at the `,`, and similarly for `Target`.

Comment: Welcome to SO Ammet. I would like to point out that it is expected practice you attempt to figure out these things on your own. If/When you do have problems then you can show us what you tried and then we can try and help you fix its. We are a community to help programmers and programming enthusiasts. We are not a code writing service

Comment: On top of what I already said including your expected output would be good as I do not know PRM format but I do know regex. This might be the case for others as well.

Comment: Matt, I have used the following regex to select ?(MAP)\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]|\.|\_|\*)+ 
But it selects everything, I need help to exclude the lines that start with '--'. 
For that I used the following, but it is not working
[^(--)](?(MAP)\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]|\.|\_|\*)+).+?

Comment: That's good. Can you update your question with the _code_ you have tried as well and what you _expect_ for output. It's nice to know you have been trying. Once we have that I know the community can help you much easier. What you have does not appear to be valid regex.

Comment: I am trying to display the things is a tabled form. The table name starting with MAP will come under one column and the table name with Target will go under next column. I am really not concerned with other text part

Comment: So you expect `AFF_INTEGRATION.SFDC_ACCOUNT` and `dbo.AFF_INTEGRATION_SFDC_ACCOUNT_EXCEPTION` to be in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply read your input file, ignore lines beginning with `--`, split and re-join the remaining lines, and write the result back to a file:

```psh
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt' |
  ? { $_ -notmatch '^(\s*$|--)' } |
  % { $_ -split '\s*,\s*' -join "`t" } |
  Set-Content 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
```

The condition `$_ -notmatch '^\s*$'` is just for skipping over blank lines. If you don't have blank lines in your input file you can remove it.

**Edit:** On second thought you could also replace the delimiters instead of splitting and re-joining the lines:

```psh
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt' |
  ? { $_ -notmatch '^(\s*$|--)' } |
  % { $_ -replace '\s*,\s*', "`t" } |
  Set-Content 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
```